# How to hide a fieldset

Tags: forms

I am trying to use hook_form_alter() to change the way a form is displayed. The form has 4 fieldsets and I only want to display one of them. How can I make these fieldsets invisible using hook_form_alter()?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's really simple.

On Drupal 6/7, set the "#access" property of the fieldset to `FALSE`, or use logic to determine visibility.
This will also hide all the content of the fieldset, and yet keep the values intact so that when the form is submitted they are not cleared, but retained.

Comment: Aye, discovering that saved me all kinds of time and pain. Plus it is super simple to use user_access('some perm') to control form elements safely in a complex system.

Comment: this doesn't work for fieldsets in D7. fieldsets are in the #groups array and none that I'm seeing there have a #access property.  Will continue digging but this answer doesn't appear to work for D7 & fieldsets.

Comment: One thing to note that I learned the hard way, but is clear in the docs: If you are populating a field a la a `hook_form_alter` ajax-based modification and you set `#access` to `false`, the value you set on the form will not be taken in.  Only set `#access` to `false` if you are not also trying to save data from this form field. (see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#access)

Answer (score 2):

I found that you had to do the following:

```
$form['last_field_in_tabgroup']['#required'] = FALSE;
```

and

```
hide($form['last_field_in_tabgroup']);
```

to make sure an empty tab doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I use the hide function, for instance

```
    hide($form['title']);
```

if you need to set certain parameters of the form before hiding it do it in this fashion

```
 $form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a module to do so: the [Hide Group (fieldset)](http://drupal.org/project/hide_group) module.

The #access property has the effect to remove entirely the fieldset from the form; my module only set it to hidden via CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hide($form['element']);` and  `show($form['element']);` if you want to be able to display the element later (for instance in a Dynamic / Ajax form).

Setting the `#access` property to False works for hiding the element, but it seems you can't subsequently set it True if you want to show it again.

Answer (score 0):

When you unset the form fields inside fieldset it should not be shown automatically, but you can also implement `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()` in your module for other cases.

You can use this guide.
https://3cwebservices.com/drupal/how-remove-fieldset-drupal-address-field