# Hide Fieldset in an Ajax Callback Function

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I have this code below:

```
function myid_templates_form($form, &$form_state){

    $form = array();

    $form['create_template'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => 'Create New ID Template',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'myid_create_template',                       
        ),  
    );  

    $form['myid_templates_editor'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Design your ID Template'),  
        '#access' => FALSE,
    );  

    return $form;
}
```

How will I show `$form['myid_templates_editor']`, when callback function `myid_create_template` is invoke?

```
//Callback function invoke by "$forms['create_template']" in myid_templates_form
function myid_create_template($form, &$form_state){
    $form['myid_templates_editor'] = array(
        '#access' => TRUE,
    );
}
```

Above code is not working.

**UPDATE:**

I changed `myid_create_template` from the above code to the code below, but nothing's changed. The field set still doesn't show.

```
//Callback function invoke by "$forms['create_template']" in myid_templates_form
function myid_create_template($form, &$form_state){

    $form['myid_templates_editor'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Design your ID Template'),  
        '#access' => TRUE,
    );      
    return $form['myid_templates_editor'];
}
```

Comment: The first error is that the AJAX callback should have just a line: `return $form['myid_templates_editor'];`. It's the form builder function to do the rest. The second error is that you are setting `$form['myid_templates_editor']` to an array containing just #access, removing even #type.

Comment: @kiamlaluno --> tried what you said, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that has worked for me.

I used ajax wrapper to refer to form wrapper to mention what to be replaced on ajax callback.

From ajax callback the wrapper has to be replaced with right content, which is the whole form in my case. so returned form from ajax callback function.

One more thing to note is, I had to change #access to TRUE for all child elements of field set. Just changing the field set's access didn't display child elements for me.

```
function test_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['test_text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Test text field',
  );

  $form['test_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Design your ID Template'),  
    '#access' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['test_fieldset']['test_text2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Text 2'),  
  );
  $form['test_btn'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Create New ID Template',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'test_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'test_form_wrapper',  
    ),
  );
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id=test_form_wrapper>';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  return $form;
}

function test_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['test_fieldset']['#access'] = TRUE;
  foreach (element_children($form['test_fieldset']) as $child) {
    $form['test_fieldset'][$child]['#access'] = TRUE;
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to embed it to the '#wrapper' attribute. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: --> Hey your code really helps but this code only traverse through the first child of the $form[test_fieldset], what about all the child/granchild of the element?

Comment: Hmm .. (thinking)

Comment: @Aliyah See if this helps. I didn't try it though http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/84526/2871